# Restriction to a fundamental domain is an isometry

Tags: manifolds, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds, isometry

Suppose the group $\Gamma$ acts on a Riemannian manifold $M$ by isometries and properly and discontinuously. Let $\pi : M \to M/\Gamma$ be the quotient map, which is a Riemannian covering map if we endow $M/\Gamma$ with the right metric. For $p \neq q \in M$, define

$$H_{p,q} = \{ x \in M : d(p, x) < d(q,x) \}.$$

The fundamental domain of $\Gamma$ centered at $p \in M$ is

$$\Delta_p = \bigcap_{g \in \Gamma \setminus \{e\} } H_{p, g(p)} = \{ x \in M : d(p, x)< d(g(p), x) \text{ for all } g \in \Gamma \setminus \{e\} \}.$$

Facts about $\Delta_p$ can be found in [this paper](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.tmj/1178241180). **Is it true that $\pi$ restricted to $\Delta_p$ is an isometry?** It suffices to show that this restriction is injective.

Comment: If $M=S^2,\ \Gamma=\mathbb{Z}_2$, then $\pi$ is not isometry but it is injective on $\Delta_p$.

Comment: Local isometry plus injectivity does not imply isometry?

Comment: Yes. The above example shows. Maybe, we need more condition simply connected

Comment: I'm not understanding you

Comment: In fact, I managed to prove right now that the restriction is injective, thus solving the problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that $x,\ y\in \Delta_p$ and $\pi (x)=\pi(y)$. In further
assume that $d(p,y)\geq d(p,x)$.

Then $y\in \pi^{-1}(\pi (x))$ so that there is $g$ s.t. $gx=y$.

So $$ d(p,y)\geq d(p,x)=d(gp,gx)=d(gp,y) $$ That is, $y$ is not in
$\Delta_p$. It is a contradiction.